# How do I describe the situation where there are two versions of the same manual and there is a contradiction between them

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

so I encountered this problem recently. I found a product has two different versions of the manual. And there are sections that are contradictory to each other in both versions. For example, there is a `Section A` in both versions, which describes how to maintain the product after using it. But one version's `Section A` is described differently than the other version.

My question is, what are some of the possible, natural-sounding ways to describe this situations

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to clarify? What's wrong with "contradiction"? Can you provide an example sentence? And just to be clear, how are they different? Slightly different wording, or actually contradictory (e.g. A1 says "Do not put in water", but A2 says "Put in water")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described is quite clear, and you should state accordingly.

I suggest the following:

'The two versions of the product manual have sections that are contradictory to each other.  For example, their Section A, on product maintenance, are described differently.'